# iPhone/iPad's Document Directory usage limit

Tags: ipad, memory-management, ios6, memory-leaks

I am working on an application where I have to store approximately 200 photos captured from camera in Documents directory. I know that there has to be some limit on the usage of Documents Directory, and if used in excess it may result in Low Memory Situations.Can you people tell me what is the max usage limit, if any. What are the different scenarios to be considered while doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limit. Limit is your device's available disk space. People will tell that there is 2GB limit but that is wrong. That is the app's size limit.

No it will not result in low memory situations if used in excess considering you are handling your objects properly like you do in any app.